# Access to path wwwroot is denied even though I have permission

Tags: c#, iis, permissions, windows-7, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using this code to upload a file to the (Windows 7) server

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(string office, IFormFile file)
{
    var webRootPath  = _environment.WebRootPath;
    var floorPlanPath =  _configuration["SydneyFloorplanPath"];

    if (file.Length > 0) {
        var filePath1 = Path.Combine(floorPlanPath,webRootPath.ReplaceFirst("/", ""));

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath1, FileMode.Create)) {
            file.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new{office = office});
}
```

It works great when debugging in VSCode, but after publishing I get

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LogonChecker\wwwroot' is denied.

on the `new FileStream` line..

- I granted full control permissions for that folder for the user running the app pool
- I changed the application pool identity to Network Service and also granted full control permissions
- I enabled Anonymous Authentication ISS and tried to set it to both "use Application Pool Identity" and "specific user" (for which I specified a user who has full control permissions on the folder)
- I tried unchecking the "read only" box in the folder properties, but whenever I look again it is rechecked...
- I refreshed the site and recycled the app pool after making each of the above changes

I'm using IIS 6.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: You can’t writ to a folder as if it is file irrespective of permissions

Comment: Did you set permissions on that folder for IIS_IUSRS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember you need to set permissions on that folder for IIS_IUSRS so that your process can access it.